# Editing html file with bash sed

Tags: html, linux, bash, sed, terminal

I've generated a html table in bash, stored it in a variable and need to replace a specific region in a html with it.

```
sed -r -i~ -e "s/(var filesystem=)(.*)/var filesystem=\"$filesystem_table\";/g" ./Html/xmon/xmon.html
```

Basically i've turned the df -h bash output to a table and want to insert it with help of javascript into my page.

All my attempts return

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unterminated `s' command
```

Is there no easier way to do this?

The value of $filesystem_table is: (corrected)

```
<tr> <td> Filesystem </td> <td> Size </td> <td> Used </td> <td> Avail </td> <td> Use% </td> <td> Mounted </td> </tr> <tr> <td> /dev/sda1 </td> <td> 94G </td> <td> 80G </td> <td> 9.3G </td> <td> 90% </td> <td> / </td> </tr> <tr> <td> none </td> <td> 2.0G </td> <td> 328K </td> <td> 2.0G </td> <td> 1% </td> <td> /dev </td> </tr> <tr> <td> none </td> <td> 2.0G </td> <td> 2.4M </td> <td> 2.0G </td> <td> 1% </td> <td> /dev/shm </td> </tr> <tr> <td> none </td> <td> 2.0G </td> <td> 372K </td> <td> 2.0G </td> <td> 1% </td> <td> /var/run </td> </tr> <tr> <td> none </td> <td> 2.0G </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 2.0G </td> <td> 0% </td> <td> /var/lock </td> </tr> <tr> <td> /dev/sda3 </td> <td> 198G </td> <td> 184G </td> <td> 15G </td> <td> 93% </td> <td> /media/Zeta </td> </tr> <tr> <td> /dev/mmcblk0p1 </td> <td> 7.7G </td> <td> 477M </td> <td> 7.2G </td> <td> 7% </td> <td> /media/NIKON </td> </tr>
```

Solved! Partially thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.

This is how I convert the outpout of 'df -h' to a html table:

```
df -h > /tmp/filesystem
            echo "<table>" > /tmp/filesystem_table
            cat /tmp/filesystem | while read line
            do
            echo "<tr>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "<td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo $line | awk '{ print $1; }' >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "</td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "<td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo $line | awk '{ print $2; }' >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "</td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "<td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo $line | awk '{ print $3; }' >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "</td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "<td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo $line | awk '{ print $4; }' >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "</td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "<td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo $line | awk '{ print $5; }' >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "</td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "<td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo $line | awk '{ print $6; }' >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "</td>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            echo "</tr>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table
            done    
            echo "</table>" >> /tmp/filesystem_table

            filesystem_table="$($_CMD cat /tmp/filesystem_table)"
            filesystem_table="$($_CMD echo $filesystem_table)"  


            sed -r -i~ -e "s!(var filesystem=)(.*)!var filesystem=\"$filesystem_table\";!g" ./Html/xmon/xmon.html
```

Comment: What's the value of `$filesystem_table`? Or, if you didn't mean that to be a variable, kill two birds with one stone: change your outer double quotes to single quotes and you won't have to escape the inner double quotes.

Comment: My bad -- I suppose I will need to escape them all and unescape in javascript for this to actually work?

Comment: No, you need to use a different delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `/` in your env var. Use a different delimiter.

```
s!foo!bar!g
```

Comment: I've tried changing the delimiter to:
sed -r -i~ -e "s!(var filesystem=)(.*)!var filesystem=\"$filesystem_table\"!g" ./Html/xmon/xmon.html still seems problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a lot of repetition by only specifying your output file once.

```
while ...
do
    ...
done >> /tmp/filesystem_table
```

You may not need the first temporary file at all.

```
{
echo "<table>"
df -h  | while read line
         do
             echo "<tr>"
             ...
         done
}  > /tmp/filesystem_table
```

Why use all those `echo` and `awk` commands when one call to AWK can do it all?

```
df -h | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\n</td>\n<td>\n";
                     print "<table>" }

             NR == 1 { ORS = "\n</td>\n</tr>\n";
                       $6 = $6 " " $7; NF = 6}    # fix "Mounted on"

             {
                printf "%s\n%s\n", "<tr>", "<td>"
                $1=$1    # recompute the line with new OFS and ORS
                print
             }

            END { ORS = "\n"
                  print "</table>" }' > /tmp/filesystem_table
```

You're doing some capture groups in your `sed` command, but not using them. It's unclear what your intention is.

By the way, `sed` and `df` are not part of Bash. They are separate utilities.